# Есть список super. Мы по очереди проходимся по нему и добавляем длины его значений. Но у меня в консоль почему-то выводится -1 [2] [2]?

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
for i in reversed(range(1, k + 1)):
    puper = []
    super = []
    split_point = len(list)//i
    super.append((list[:split_point]))
    list = list[split_point:]
    for e in super:
        if len(e) <= 1:
            print(-1)
            break
        elif len(e) > 1:
            puper.append(len(e))
            print(puper)
```

Comment: ваш код почему-то не выводит -1 [2] [2] ,а даёт ошибку

Comment: Да и длин у чисел нет. Приложите к вопросу рабочий код )

Comment: Все , я сделал все , что нужно , помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ваш новый код тоже не работает и выдаёт ошибку.